# Skip testmethods in custom fxcop rule

Tags: c#, code-analysis, fxcop

I am writing a custom fxcop rule which checks for Unused locals. (Yes, there is an [existing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182278.aspx) one, but I want to exclude TestMethods from being checked.)

Where Introspector shows me that the TestMethodAttribute is available at compiletime:  [image]

I can not seem to be able to actually check if the Attribute exists.

I tried the following methods:

Method 1.

```
_TestAttribType = FrameworkAssemblies.Mscorlib.GetType(Identifier.For("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting"), Identifier.For("TestMethodAttribute"));
AttributeNode testAttribute = method.GetAttribute(_TestAttribType);
if (testAttribute != null)
    return null;
```

Method 2.

```
if(method.Attributes.Any(attrib => attrib.ToString().Contains("Test")))
    return null;
```

Method 3.

```
if(method.Attributes.Any(attrib => attrib.Type == typeof(TestMethodAttribute))
    return null;
```

Method 1 would not work because Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Unittesting is not in mscorlib. The second method didn't work either, I am not sure why. Third method does not compile, because TestMethodAttribute is not supported by the FxCop-API.

How can I exclude testmethods from being checked in my FxCop-rule?

Comment: How strict do you want to be about verifying the attribute's exact type?  Do you want to ignore only MSTest `TestAttribute`, or any attribute named "TestAttribute", or any attribute that starts with or contains "Test"?

Comment: If possible I'd actually like to know both ways, if both are even possible. Am I close to the solution?

Comment: It's non-trivial to refer to a type outside the core framework assemblies, so go with the name if you can live with that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach based on the name only would be:

```
method.Attributes.Any(a => a.Type.Name.Name == "TestMethodAttribute")
```

If you want a more complete solution with some performance enhancements, take a look at the implementation of the `IsVSUnitTestMethod` method in the `MarkMembersAsStatic` rule in a decompiler.